# How do I check the day of a datestring in python?

Tags: python, datetime, anaconda

So I have a list of 8 date objects that look like this:

```
0.   June 01, 2017
1.   June 23, 2017
2.   June 13, 2017
3.   June 27, 2017
4.   June 17, 2017
5.   June 04, 2017
6.   June 09, 2017
7.   June 11, 2017
8.   June 15, 2017
```

Given the data above, how do I (for each date in the `date_list`), check if the date is a weekend (sat|sun) or not? Based on the answer, I will be assigning variables in an if-block:

```
if (date != weekend){
    weekdayCode();
} else {
    weekendCode();
}
```

Comment: Is this a python `list` or is it text in a file somewhere?  Are the dates strings or `datetime.datetime` objects?

Comment: it is indeed a `list`! The dates themselves are `strings`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parse it to a datetime and call `weekday()`.

```
import datetime

for date_string in list_of_strings:    
    dt = datetime.datetime.strptime(date_string, '%B %d, %Y')
    if dt.weekday() in (5, 6):
        print('{} is on a weekend'.format(date_string))
    else:
        print('{} is a weekday'.format(datestring))
```

Comment: The code will only work with the provided datetime format. Just a heads up for anyone planning to use it in its existing form.

Comment: Nice answer, I believe the tuple should be (0,6)

Comment: Oh no, you are right my bad! :) Weird that `weekday()` returns (5,6) for weekends but when parsing with `strptime` the weekends are (0,6)

Comment: Yeah, it's `isoweekday()` that returns it with weekends as (0, 6).